# decimal value in python, how to make it '0.00'?

Tags: python, decimal

I have problem in generating or getting decimal value in python.
for now, I am using float(), but it returns .0 not .00 ...

```
>>> d = 10
>>> float(d)
10.0
>>>
```

how can I set a decimal value that returns with .00?

```
>>10.00
```

thanks in advance ...

Comment: is this for printing and displaying the value? you do realize 10.0=10.00

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/python-limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python only displays what's needed, so it displated `10.0`

If it's the matter of printing it as 10.00.

To do that.

```
>>> d = 10
>>> print "Value: %.2f" % float(d)
Value: 10.00
>>>
```

Comment: @ Abhijeet, thanks for the reply... i try your answer but it returns into a string, i cannot do some mathematical activities...

Comment: @gadss `float(d)` already a float. I just printed it differently. Python only displayed what's needed in your case. It's actually a float only. You can continue on with your calculations without worrying about how many digits are after the decimal.

Comment: ahh.. thanks  Abhijeet Rastogi :)

Answer (score 3):

You could also use [`format`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) as follows:

```
>>> '{0:.2f}'.format(float(d))
10.00
```

Comment: this works only 00 case

Answer (score 3):

If you want your arithmetic to take into account how many digits after the period you should have, you must use the [decimal](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) module:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal("10.0")
Decimal('10.0')
>>> Decimal("10.00")
Decimal('10.00')
>>> Decimal("10.0")**2
Decimal('100.00')
>>> Decimal("10.00")**2
Decimal('100.0000')
```

I guess I also should mention the [python uncertainties module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/uncertainties/):

```
>>> from uncertainties import ufloat
>>> x = ufloat((2, 0.25))
>>> x
2.0+/-0.25
>>> square = x**2  # Transparent calculations
>>> square
4.0+/-1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Python is displaying `10.0` because you're displaying a floating point number, and Python will only display as many decimal places as is needed.

If you want to print `10.00` for display purposes, use the string formatting operator `%` like so:

```
>>> a = 10
>>> float (a)
10.0
>>> "%2.2f" % a
'10.00'
>>>
```

More about [string formatting operations](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/typesseq-strings.html).